# I would like to show list of pdf files

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I have a requirement where I need to show all the files(PDF) from a folder. I am new to windows 8.1 app development, can some one help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into any of the available libraries used to open files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Sharp Folder Search by Using Regular Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261260/c-sharp-folder-search-by-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 2):

Fir example:

```
var PDFList =  System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("Path", "*.pdf").ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but one question i have is how to show them in the mobile app is there any control that we can use

Comment: @Avinash: your welcome but your comment is a little weird, how do you usually display elements stored within a list, the approach is the same!

Comment: He wants to display the content of the PDFs not the paths/names of them. Check MuPDF(http://www.mupdf.com/) DL: https://github.com/MishaUliutin/MuPDF.WinRT

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih: Oh I thought he was speaking about the paths :p